# Javascript - How to extract filename from a file input control

Tags: javascript, browser, extract

When a user selects a file in a web page I want to be able to extract just the filename.

I did try str.search function but it seems to fail when the file name is something like this: **c:\uploads\ilike.this.file.jpg**.

How can we extract just the file name without extension?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Assuming your **<input type="file" >** has an id of **upload** this should hopefully do the trick:

```
var fullPath = document.getElementById('upload').value;
if (fullPath) {
    var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
    var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
    if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(1);
    }
    alert(filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work well, but I just want filename without extension. How can I do that in above code.

Comment: I added these two lines of code to extract just the file name without extension:
"filename = filename.substring(0,filename.length-4);
 filename = filename.toLowerCase();"

Comment: Nope, you don't want to do it that way Yogi Yang says. Instead use: `filename = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));` Because his way will fail with extensions of more characters than 3, thus: .html, .jpeg etc.

Comment: how to get the filenames in case of multiple file selection?

Comment: Why not just calculate startIndex like so? `var startIndex = Math.max(fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\'), fullPath.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1;`

Answer (score 249):

To split the string ({filepath}/{filename}) and get the file name you could use something like this:

```
str.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop()
```

> "The pop method removes the last element from an array and returns that
>   value to the caller."
>   [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Example:

from: `"/home/user/file.txt".split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop()`

you get: `"file.txt"`

Comment: You can also do that just with regexes and without any array operation: `var filename = filepath.replace(/^.*?([^\\\/]*)$/, '$1');`

Comment: vog's answer is really close to the 100% accurate answer to the question (except needs to strip the extension.)
A filename is no different from any other string.

Comment: The split regex can be shortened to `[\\/]`. Moreover, it was asked for stripping the file extension, too. For a complete solution, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32156800/19163

Comment: I think the 'longer' regex version of `(\\|\/)` (vs the short `[\\/]`) handles different path name syntax on different OSs, no? Its `C:\path\Filename.ext`on Windows, and `home/path/Filename.ext`on linux and macOs?

Answer (score 175):

Nowadays there is a much simpler way:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('upload');   
var filename = fileInput.files[0].name;
```

Comment: Check `fileInput.files.length` before calling `.name`, in case the user clicked cancel.

Answer (score 45):

Very simple

```
let file = $("#fileupload")[0].files[0]; 
file.name
```

Comment: In case you're using TypeScript then its $("#fileupload")[0]["files"][0];

Comment: fwiw This works in 2022

Answer (score 29):

Assuming:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="theFile">
```

The JavaScript would be:

```
var fileName = document.getElementById('theFile').files[0].name;
```

Answer (score 9):

I assume you want to strip all extensions, i.e. `/tmp/test/somefile.tar.gz` to `somefile`.

Direct approach with regex:

```
var filename = filepath.match(/^.*?([^\\/.]*)[^\\/]*$/)[1];
```

Alternative approach with regex and array operation:

```
var filename = filepath.split(/[\\/]/g).pop().split('.')[0];
```

Comment: This doesn't strip the extension, as asked for.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 8):

```
var pieces = str.split('\\');
var filename = pieces[pieces.length-1];
```

Comment: This assumes that the user is running Windows. Other operating systems use different file path seperators.

Comment: Would you need to check for the '/' character as well for non-Windows users e.g. if (!pieces) { str.split('/'); }? Nice simple solution though +1

Comment: IIRC, IE is the only browser that gives the full path of the file anyway...   You won't need to split on other browsers like Firefox, so it still works.

Although I admit I haven't tried EVERY linux/unix browser.

Comment: str.split(/(\\|\/)/g);  for windows and *nix

Comment: @TM. Chrome uses a fake path variable for safety which is ugly; iirc it is different depending on what OS you are on.

Comment: Oddly enough, it is only the Windows user interface and compilers that care whether you use "\" or "/" for directory separator.  The internal Win32 and kernel libraries treat them the same.

Answer (score 6):

**Input**: `C:\path\Filename.ext`
**Output**: `Filename`

In HTML code, set the File `onChange` value like this...

```
<input type="file" name="formdata" id="formdata" onchange="setfilename(this.value)"/>
```

Assuming your textfield id is 'wpName'...

```
<input type="text" name="wpName" id="wpName">
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
  function setfilename(val)
  {
    filename = val.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
    filename = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
    document.getElementById('wpName').value = filename;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I just made my own version of this. My function can be used to extract whatever you want from it, if you don't need all of it, then you can easily remove some code.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Useful function to separate path name and extension from full path string
function pathToFile(str)
{
    var nOffset = Math.max(0, Math.max(str.lastIndexOf('\\'), str.lastIndexOf('/')));
    var eOffset = str.lastIndexOf('.');
    if(eOffset < 0 && eOffset < nOffset)
    {
        eOffset = str.length;
    }
    return {isDirectory: eOffset === str.length, // Optionally: && nOffset+1 === str.length if trailing slash means dir, and otherwise always file
            path: str.substring(0, nOffset),
            name: str.substring(nOffset > 0 ? nOffset + 1 : nOffset, eOffset),
            extension: str.substring(eOffset > 0 ? eOffset + 1 : eOffset, str.length)};
}

// Testing the function
var testcases = [
    "C:\\blabla\\blaeobuaeu\\testcase1.jpeg",
    "/tmp/blabla/testcase2.png",
    "testcase3.htm",
    "C:\\Testcase4", "/dir.with.dots/fileWithoutDots",
    "/dir.with.dots/another.dir/"
];
for(var i=0;i<testcases.length;i++)
{
    var file = pathToFile(testcases[i]);
    document.write("- " + (file.isDirectory ? "Directory" : "File") + " with name '" + file.name + "' has extension: '" + file.extension + "' is in directory: '" + file.path + "'<br />");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Will output the following:

- File with name 'testcase1' has extension: 'jpeg' is in directory: 'C:\blabla\blaeobuaeu'
- File with name 'testcase2' has extension: 'png' is in directory: '/tmp/blabla'
- File with name 'testcase3' has extension: 'htm' is in directory: ''
- Directory with name 'Testcase4' has extension: '' is in directory: 'C:'
- Directory with name 'fileWithoutDots' has extension: '' is in directory: '/dir.with.dots'
- Directory with name '' has extension: '' is in directory: '/dir.with.dots/another.dir'

With `&& nOffset+1 === str.length` added to `isDirectory`:

- File with name 'testcase1' has extension: 'jpeg' is in directory: 'C:\blabla\blaeobuaeu'
- File with name 'testcase2' has extension: 'png' is in directory: '/tmp/blabla'
- File with name 'testcase3' has extension: 'htm' is in directory: ''
- Directory with name 'Testcase4' has extension: '' is in directory: 'C:'
- Directory with name 'fileWithoutDots' has extension: '' is in directory: '/dir.with.dots'
- Directory with name '' has extension: '' is in directory: '/dir.with.dots/another.dir'

Given the testcases you can see this function works quite robustly compared to the other proposed methods here.

Note for newbies about the \\: \ is an escape character, for example \n means a newline and \t a tab. To make it possible to write \n, you must actually type \\n.

Comment: Watch out for this path: **dir.with.dots/fileWithoutDots** as you will get eOffset less than nOffset and confuse the extraction expressions.

Comment: Yeah, fixed it. Now that should work properly too (added `&& eOffset < nOffset`).

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the highly upvoted answers actually provide "just the file name without extension" and the other solutions are way too much code for such a simple job.

I think this should be a one-liner to any JavaScript programmer. It's a very simple regular expression:

```
function basename(prevname) {
    return prevname.replace(/^(.*[/\\])?/, '').replace(/(\.[^.]*)$/, '');
}
```

First, strip anything up to the last slash, if present.

Then, strip anything after the last period, if present.

It's simple, it's robust, it implements exactly what's asked for. Am I missing something?

Comment: "a very simple regular expression" ... Well, actually these are two regexes. :-) See my answer for a single-regex solution.

Comment: Yes, there is also an obvious re-write to pack those two regexes into a single regex using the pipe (|) operator. I think the code as written is clearer, but it does run through the string twice, which would be a problem if the string is generally pretty long. (File paths typically aren't, but can be.)

Comment: I was just nitpicking. Please don't take that seriously. There is no need to optimize, all proposed solutions are more than fast enough.  Very long file paths are still kilobytes, not gigabytes. And this function will be triggered once per file upload, not 1000x in a batch. The only things that matter here are correctness and clarity of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Easy Path:

JQuery

```
$("#fileInputId").on("change", () => {
    alert($("#fileInputId")[0].files[0].name);
});
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("fileInputId").onchange = function() {
   alert(document.getElementById("fileInputId").files[0].name)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// HTML
<input type="file" onchange="getFileName(this)">

// JS
function getFileName(input) {
    console.log(input.files[0].name) // With extension
    console.log(input.files[0].name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '')) // Without extension
}
```

[How to remove the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250408/1355416)

Comment: This misses an important part of the question, "extract just the file name without extension". It helps to read the question carefully first before jumping to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = document.getElementById('upload').value;//take path
var tokens= path.split('\\');//split path
var filename = tokens[tokens.length-1];//take file name
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me, here is my solution which updates a disabled input with the filename:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.getElementById('img_name').onchange = function () {
  var filePath = this.value;
    if (filePath) {
      var fileName = filePath.replace(/^.*?([^\\\/]*)$/, '$1');
      document.getElementById('img_name_input').value = fileName;
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using jQuery then

```
$("#fileupload").val();
```

Comment: val() would actually return the whole file path which is what he doesn't want.

Comment: That gives the entire path and not only the name which is not what OP is asking for.