# how to pass uploaded file name to java script asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery

for the

```
<input type="file" name="addfile" id="addfile" />
 <input type="submit" id="btnadd" value="Addfile" onclick="filetype(addfile)" />
```

i need to check the file type(pdf or doc etc) in javascript that is added for this what do i need to pass in filetype onclick function to have addfile name passed instead of addfile passed in it ?

thanks,

michaeld

Comment: Question is not clear please provide more details

Comment: Passed where? To the server-side?

Comment: thnx for comments  i have edited the question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first you need to extract the filename from `addfile` after its added, like as mentioned here: [Javascript - How to extract filename from a file input control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857618/javascript-how-to-extract-filename-from-a-file-input-control)

and then use that inside `filetype`.

Comment: hi Mrchief the code gives me file name like new.txt, file.xml , what to add to have only  extension like .txt, .xml

Comment: Try this: `var ext = filename.split('.')[1]; // filename.split('.')[0] will be jsut the name`

Comment: i tried like this  while (fullPath.indexOf("\\") != -1)
            fullPath = fullPath.slice(file.indexOf("\\") + 1);
        ext = fullPath.slice(fullPath.indexOf(".")).toLowerCase(); it also wrkd ,thanks mrchief

Comment: Yeah, that'd work too. I just prefer `split` as it is shorter and cleaner and doesn't make calculate those pesky indexes.