# Obtaining name of uploaded image with servlet 3.0

Tags: java, image, jsp, file-upload, servlet-3.0

Hello i am making a servlet that gets the image from a

Everything in my servlet works fine. The only problem is that i want to know what is the name of the uploaded image so that i can store its full path in a database. How to i so that?

This is the code that upload the file but, it doesn't provide me the actual name of the original image. f.getName gives me the name of my  tag.

```
Part f= request.getPart("imgCoverInserisci");
InputStream imageInputStream = f.getInputStream();
System.out.println("Path where image will be saved: "+request.getContextPath()+"/Immagini/");
   /*returns null*/        String     nomeFile=request.getParameter("imgCoverInserisci");
   f.getName(); //return name of input tag
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream ("C:\\Users\\Salvatore\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TestFumettopoli\\web\\Immagini\\copertineFumetti\\"+nomeFile);
// write bytes taken from uploaded file to target file
int ch = imageInputStream.read();
while (ch != -1) {
                  out.write(ch);
                  ch = imageInputStream.read();
}
out.close();
imageInputStream.close();
```

Comment: use Apache commons, it has a module for file uploading in servlet, and also returns the client file name

Comment: is there any way to do it in servlet 3.0 ?

Comment: yes dude it works with servlet 3 too :)

Comment: check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm) and [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in a different way. I used javascript to parse the name of the file image everytime the Onchange event occured. The javascript function then assigned the name of the file in a hidden input tag. Later the servlet only needed to read this as a parameter and the trick is done!

the javascript code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857618/javascript-how-to-extract-filename-from-a-file-input-control)