# how to get the file name from input feild with javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

please somebody help me out on this. I want to get the file name from `<input type="file" id="photo1" name="photo1"/>` I need the file name with no path and extension!
I try to get the data with this `var pic = document.getElementById("photo1").value;` but is not working!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: does that get full path or don't get anything?

Comment: Solved in earlier post.. [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857618/javascript-how-to-extract-filename-from-a-file-input-control)

Comment: This might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857618/javascript-how-to-extract-filename-from-a-file-input-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/BLGg4/1/

```
var btn = document.getElementById("clickme");

btn.onclick = function() {
   var pic = document.getElementById("photo1").value.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();   
   var filename = pic.substring(0, pic.lastIndexOf("."));
   alert(filename); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fiddle for You: http://jsfiddle.net/rzvcy/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('#ddd').on('click' , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var pic = document.getElementById("photo1").value;
        var answer = pic.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
        alert(answer);
    });
});
```

Edit: In http://jsfiddle.net/rzvcy/3/  You've got only name of the file

```
    var answer = answer.split(/\./g);
```

Comment: thank you very much it's helped me out a little, but I want only the name, not the extension too.

Comment: Updated my answer :) Hope that's what are You looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created small fiddle for you please check [a http://jsfiddle.net/7cVE5/](http://jsfiddle.net/7cVE5/)

> $("input[type=file]").change(function() {
>
> > ```
> >      var filename = $(this).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
> >      $("#test_text_box").val(filename);
> > ```
> >
> > });

Comment: /^C:\\fakepath\\/  Really? What if he's gonna change a path or OS of server? He will have to change it in every .js file with this code. Sorry, but that's just not "cool" solution. :)

Comment: This does: "replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');" That was the code i did comment. Not current code.

Comment: Ok :) Good we understand each other now  :)