# yii2 get filepath of the uploaded local file

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-components

I want to ask about how to get the file path of the file i want to upload from file input, the code is like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
```

the problem is i want to automatically send the file as attachment of email without uploading the file to hosting, which required the path of local file

```
 ->attach('C:/Users/User/Downloads/file/file.pdf')
```

I want to get file path like

```
'C:/Users/User/Downloads/file/file.pdf'
```

is it possible? or there is another method to fix my problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857618/javascript-how-to-extract-filename-from-a-file-input-control

Comment: okay, trying to do with java script, i will update the result later

Comment: Check yii2 doc: `http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html`

Comment: hi @kalu I already read those documentation, but i haven't found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check yii2 doc. [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html]
if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
       $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
       $tempFilePath = $model->imageFile->tempName;
       //Send Email.
    }
```

Comment: sorry for late update, it work, but i already used some code from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46660315/yii2-form-to-send-attachment ,thanks