# How to retrieve the selected filename using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using the following code to display a file selection dialog in an angular application and I'm not sure how to retrieve the selected filename.

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
    Import
    <input type="file"
           change="change()" hidden>
</label>
```

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Comment: are you looking for a vanilla js solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to extract filename from a file input control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857618/javascript-how-to-extract-filename-from-a-file-input-control)

Answer (score 1):

First, pass event reference into input change:

```
<input type="file" change="change( e )" hidden>
```

Second, retrieve the name from event target:

```
function change( e ) {
      const files = e.target.files;
      const file = files[0];
      const file_name = file.name;
}
```

Read some docs on input file. Such as this [@Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

NOTE:

If you have troubles with the onchange event, assign some id to your input, perhaps like this:

```
<input type="file" id="file_input">
```

and then query for the element by that id, like this:

```
document.getElementById('file_input').onchange = function( e ) {
      const files = e.target.files;
      const file = files[0];
      const file_name = file.name;
      alert(file_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it turns out what I was missing, I failed to mention it was that this is an angular application. To get to the selected file, I had to change to

```
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                Import
                <input type="file"
                       (change)="change($event)" hidden>
            </label>
```

then in the function, the selected filename is in event.target.files[0].name.

```
    public change($event): void {
    let that = this;
    let files = $event.target.files;
}
```

thank you all for the responses.