# Name of file selected in file field

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using JQuery to read filename selected by the user using val() method and it's working fine but it's breaking on IE. Can someone help?

```
var filename = $('[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
```

The above is working fine in chrome, safari and Mozilla but not in IE 10.

Comment: Maybe you should include some code!!

Comment: edit your question instead of adding code in the comment section

Comment: Please visit this link i hope it may work,
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857618/javascript-how-to-extract-filename-from-a-file-input-control**

Comment: "Not working" is not a valid error. Please console.log before and after and tell us any console errors. There are browsers that return fakepath for example