# how to upload a file in localhost web server, and get the file path

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, localhost

I've deployed a web localhost, http://localhost:8080
and I included the following code to take a upload file.

```
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

I am trying to read file name and file path in the local web server in my javascript code.
How can I get those two?

Comment: Do these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40439593/6548154 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function to get the name, file path, size, and some other information about the uploaded file.

```js
const handleUploadClick = (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0]
  console.log(file) // returns an object
}
```